# CocoaPod : Unable to remove the Pod from project

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods

I have a xcode (iOS) project in which i am cocoapods.
I have couple of pods installed:
**SwiftHTTP & SwiftyJSON**.

Now for some reason I decided to try another pod namely [EZAlertController](https://github.com/thellimist/EZAlertController). Nothing wrong with the pod. But i decided not to use it. So I need to uninstall this pod from my project.
So far whatI have done:

1. remove pod 'EZAlertController', '0.3'from the podfile
2. run pod install which gave me the message of

> Removing EZAlertController

3. No **EZAlertController** folder in the **Pods** folder either. So far so good.
4. Now i closed the xcode and reran the **.xcworkspace** file.
5. clean & build routine - **all good - Again**

P.S.(also tried pod update)

**The Problem:**
I am still able to **import EZAlertController** into the project and run. What is really annoying is that I forgot to take a git snapshot. So **can't just revert back** without loosing considerable amount of code.

Any idea on how to completely get rid of EZAlertController even after removing as there is still some linking with xcode :(

Comment: Try to delete references to the pod under following Build Phases: 
- Copy Pods Resources
- Embed Pods Frameworks
- Check Pods Manifest.lock

Comment: the reference for EZAlertController wasn't present under Build Phases: - Copy Pods Resources. Also the Manifest.lock file was good too and didn't had any reference for EZAlertController

Comment: If you didn't use Cocopods (especially for these small unneeded dependencies), you could have just deleted the dependency and been done with it. Food for thought. (Instead of adding something to manipulate your workspace).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to clean the project: `Product -> Clean` and also `Product -> (hold option key) Clean Build Folder`

Comment: Did use Product -> Clean. that doesn't help. But Product -> (hold option key) Clean Build Folder did the trick. Didn't know that that option was there

Answer (score 0):

Maybe deleting the derived data could resolve your issue

Comment: haven't tried that but will try that if i run into this problem again. but the accepted answer did the trick for the moment

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't remove the pod. I've had this problem before. I tried blowing away all the pods but continued to experience the problem. What I would do is blow away all the pods, reinstall Cocoapods to the project, then try installing it again.

Alternatively you can add the framework you need manually.